# If $\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega$ open connection and $u \equiv 0$ in an open subset of $\Omega$, then $u \equiv 0$ in $\Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u$ harmonic on an open connected $\Omega$ and suppose that there is an open subset of $\Omega$ where $u \equiv 0$. Prove that $u \equiv 0$ in every $\Omega$.

**Solution sketch:** I took the set $$A = \{x \in \Omega; \ u(x) = 0\}$$ and I tried to show that its interior is closed in $\Omega$, so that $int A$ would be opened and closed in $\Omega$. So, by the $\Omega$ connectivity, we would have
$$\Omega = int A,$$
which would prove the problem.$\Omega$.

I cannot verify that $int A$ is closed. It is possible? Can you help me? Is this the way to solve it?

Comment: The max/min principle for harmonic functions comes to mind.

Comment: Integrating against functions of $C^\infty_0(\Omega) = \{ \varphi\in C^\infty(\Omega), \ \varphi = 0 \text{ on } \partial\Omega\}$, you get that $\nabla u = 0$ a.e. in $\Omega$ and thus $u=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$. Though I am not sure how to deal with the case where $A\subset \partial\Omega$. Probably the maximum principle like @zhw mentioned is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that harmonic functions are analytic.
Then just use the power series expansion of this function，we can clearly get every limit point of the interior of A has an neighborhood where the function is vanishing.

Comment: I had seen this result involving harmonic functions and I confess that, at first, it was not clear. However, I think your explanation helped because
since $u$ in $\Omega$ is analytic, then for every $a \in \Omega$ there must be complex numbers $C_{\alpha}$ such that
$$u(x) = \sum C_{\alpha}(x - a)$$
for every $x$ in a neighborhood of $a$, the series absolutely converges on that neighborhood. In this way, $a \in \mbox{int}(A)$, because by the continuity of $u$, we have
$$u(a_n) \rightarrow u(a)$$
and $u(a_n) = 0$ for a sufficiently small neighborhood of $a_n$.